# What could cause this poor performance of neo4j?

Tags: java, profiling, rdf, neo4j

In our stack, we use neo4j and have encountered classical performance issues : application is slow as hell as soon as it requires data from [neo4j](http://neo4j.org/).

Listening only my courage (pun intended) I started JVisualVM and done a profiling of application.

This application is hosted in a JavaEE server (Glassfish) and uses a quasi-semantic stack made of [Empire-RDF](https://github.com/mhgrove/Empire), [Blueprints](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/), and [neo4j](http://neo4j.org/). Access to neo4j is offered by [JCA neo4j-connector](https://github.com/alexsmirnov/neo4j-connector).

Like this screenshot suggests, there is strong evidence that there is a bottleneck in neo4j data retrieval.

[image: Interesting fragments of a profiling session]

My question is double, but simple.

1. Is that performance level normal ? (I guess no)
2. What can I do to improve those performances ?

**EDIT** here are some informations regarding the test procdure that should enlighten both of you.

My graph structure is, to me, unknown : as I'm using Empire-RDF on top of Blueprints/Sesame/Neo4J, I only know the Java objects I'm manipulating, which are ten intereconnected classes, and they unfortunatly are at the very core of our buisness, so I can't disclose them.

Consider, for the sake of this example, they create a tree of visual elements linked to entities representing URI targets.

I have a maven test that runs a combination of read/write operation (I will say there is between 20 and 50 JPA operations involved). This maven test runs in 300 **seconds**.

On a lower level,

- application is run on Windows-7 and Mac OS X 10.6, with various sub-versions of Java 1.6.
- Application is hosted on a Glassfish 3.1.1
- neo4j DB is version 1.5, accessed through [neo4j-connector](https://github.com/alexsmirnov/neo4j-connector) for JCA (there is no customization made to default settings).
- Sesame is version 2.6.0
- blueprints is version 1.1
- Empire-RDF is version 0.7

As a last world, diving into jVisualVM sampler reveals most of the application time is spent in those `NodeManager#getNodeForProxy` calls.

Comment: We've had nothing but good results with Neo4J so far. We're just using it plain vanilla though. Did you point to this question to the folks on the mailing list?

Comment: I think that's the catch, using neo4j as a graph database, you'll get good performance.  But when you try and jam an RDF view of the world on top of it is when you get into trouble.  SPARQL is quite join-heavy, and for something like Empire that generates pretty complex queries, something that is not natively designed to do those joins efficiently will have a lot of trouble.

Comment: Could you please provide more information: versions, size and structure of your graph, which operations do you want to perform, your gremlin code, jvm-memory settings, neo4j settings (mmio), OS, and if only 0.2% of your profiling time are spent in neo4j I don't know if that is really the issue?

Comment: joins should be no issue with Neo4j as it is a graphdb, I think it is something else.

Comment: could you perhaps provide a demo project / usecase that shows this behaviour ? perhaps without the glassfish / jca overhead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, time to put an end to that joke, and thanks to both Mike who helped me.

Performance problem was not neo4J 1.5 fault, nor Empire, neither Blueprints one, but rather my poor understanding of my own persistence stack.

Do you remember I said used neo4j instance was obtained from a JCA connector ?

Well, I used version 0.2 of that connector, which worked with neo4j 1.4 ... Yes, 1.4 !

Fortunatly, I already had prepared an upgrade of that version, allowing me to send parameters directly to neo4j (like setting cache_type). So [I finished that upgrade](https://github.com/Riduidel/neo4j-connector/commit/95d9e1b492823edcf7f3bcdc7ae4f75831255a12), bundled it, deployed it to my local repository, integrated it into my domain, tested, and ... success ! a **x20** improvement of performances !

Comment: glad to hear that it worked out, could you perhaps share your upgrade of the connector, and a blog post about this stack would be great!

Answer (score 3):

The last time I used the neo4j Sail, I was immensely disappointed with the performance.  Inserts, even bulk inserts, were unacceptably slow, and anything but the most simple queries were too slow for any sort of user-facing interface.

Granted, this was about two years ago, so it's likely the performance is different (perhaps even better) than the last time I looked at it, but at the time it was so far behind all the dedicated RDF databases, I don't imagine they've caught up.

neo4j is good if you're using it as a graph store, but I don't think it's well suited to RDF.  You're going to be much better off using a real RDF database.  Since you're using Empire, it ought to be easy to drop in most any other RDF database and see how that affects performance, assuming you're not relying on anything neo4j/Blueprints specific.  If that's the case, [Stardog](http://stardog.com) includes bindings for Blueprints, which might be worth looking at.